# Can a break/split a Row in sql into two different rows and display them as two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not trying to be stupid but that's the requirement that I have.

My table:
[image Mytable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jcXR.png)

I am currently stuck with this query and couldn't think further than taking all of them in one single row.

My query:

```
select ID, Date, Name, INTime, ID, Date, Name, OutTime from Mytable
```

Output i need:
[image output i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqiZv.png)

Comment: Sorry for the typo in question, i mean 'CAN I BREAK/SPLIT"

Comment: `SELECT ID, Date, Name, INTime FROM Mytable CONCAT SELECT ID, Date, Name, OutTime from Mytable;` might be a good start for you. Just some sorting needed.

Comment: `mysql` or `sqlserver` ?

Comment: Please include all information in the question (edit it) not in images.

Comment: Its sql server  @Abhishek

Comment: cramopy, abhishek and richard thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ID, Date, Name, INTime  from Mytable
union all
select ID, Date, Name, OutTime from Mytable
order by ID, INTime asc
```

Comment: Thank you so much, helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a  select UNION

```
select ID, Date, Name, INTime
from Mytable 
union all 
select ID, Date, Name, OUTtime
from Mytable 
Order by NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you could use `APPLY` operator

```
SELECT a.* FROM table t
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (t.id, t.date, t.name, t.in),
           (t.id, t.date, t.name, t.out)
)a
```